# Unable to successfully Encode UIImage and store in Database

Tags: ios, image, encoding, swift2, alamofire

I'm looking to convert a UIImage to NSData (this part works), then encode that NSData into a string so that I can store into my database through an Alamofire POST request.
Here is the code I have so far and the different encoding methods I have tried in Swift 2:

```
let a = spaceImage.image
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(a!)

//First method
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

//Second method
let base64String2 = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

//Third method
let base64String3 = String(data: imageData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

So there was a specific issue with each of these methods.

First Method, I get this error:

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Second Method, I get the same error as the first method:

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Third Method, When I print this string, it is nil so that is clearly not working either.

Keep in mind, I am using Swift 2 and Alamofire to make the POST requests (encoding in JSON). What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is alamorefire bug i guess. in your post code if you're calling

```
Alamorefire.request().responseJSON()
```

try this insted of that.

```
Alamorefire.request().responseString()
```

Comment: When I do response string, I get the following error, even though the request worked:

`<body><h1>request entity too large</h1><h2>413</h2><pre>Error: request entity too large` 

When I look in the database, the item that I am trying to post is clearly not there. Any other help?

Comment: seems like this is server issue... can you just send small characters and check. may be let base64String3 = "hello world" . try this . in your request ?